# Change display with animations without using react router

Tags: reactjs

I have a sign-in screen using react. When I press the `Don't have an account?` link I don't want the traditional load and show me a page setup, rather I want some animations to happen in the page that makes it look like it's native, using reactjs.

What should I do to achieve that?

I will attach screenshots:

[image: First screeen]

[image: The second screen after animation]

Comment: Remember that the code is more helpful than some screens (Of course both are better), could you add what are you trying so we can have more info to help you to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit older react login demo i built on codepen that could give you idea of how I approached this issue.

Basically, I conditioned the `content` component with state value `authorized: 1||0` and based on that value i am swapping content served.

From there, all I have to do is animate content and execute on state update.

https://codepen.io/mihaelnikic/pen/roMrgw